# is there any Ansible playbook to spin up a Tezos node from sources or binary? (not from docker image)

Tags: node, setup, snapshots

is there any Ansible playbook to spin up a Tezos node from sources or binary? (not from docker image)

preferable for an Archive Mainnet node, but any resource is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a bit of work in this direction : https://gitlab.com/abate/ansible-tezos-docker-run/-/tree/master

@Nomadic-Labs we are working to provide well tested and working ansible playbooks. Hopefully coming soon.

#### Update

From source : some old work 
https://gitlab.com/abate/ansible-roles/-/tree/master/tezos-source

Comment: thanks Pietro but i cant use docker, Im looking something from sources or bin

Comment: have a look here then. This is some old work I didn't have time to keep up to date. https://gitlab.com/abate/ansible-roles/-/tree/master/tezos-source